# Has anyone heard of a model similar to a random forest which fits a linear regression model in its leaf nodes?

Tags: random-forest, linear-regression

That is, each leaf node in each decision tree learns a linear model.

Anyone heard of this kind of model? Even better, anyone know of implementations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[M5P Model Trees](https://github.com/ankonzoid/LearningX/tree/master/advanced_ML/model_tree) are the closest thing that I'm aware of.  In these trees, the leaf nodes are linear models.  The difference is that the leaf nodes learn a multi-dimensional linear model instead of single-dimensional.
(If you had a single-dimensional model at the leaf, how would you know which feature to use in the regression?  What is the advantage over multi-dimensional?)

Of course a model tree is just a single tree, not a forest.  But you could easily build a random forest composed of model trees.

Comment: you're right. no reason to restrict to one dimensional